raspberry Pi Pico, writing char array to file on SD Card
I'm using the pico C++ SDK and VS Code on windows 10 pc. I'm simply trying to write to a file on an SD card. The library used is: FatFs - Generic FAT Filesystem Module  R0.15 w/patch1.
The code shown in the function below runs without error, the file is created but no data is written to the file. The FA_OPEN_APPEND flag is used because the goal is to continuously update the file with a new line of data (like a log file). The data passed into the function is of type struct (params). The params structure is verified to be correct because in the code I print the char msg_buf which uses sprintf to load it.  The I've tried three file write functions with the same results: f_printf, f_puts and f_write.  Perhaps msg_buf is not in the correct encoding? Any assistance is appreciated.
bool write_params(struct event_params params) {
    // Open file for append
    fr = f_open(&fil, filename, FA_OPEN_APPEND);
    if (fr != FR_OK) {
        printf("failed to open file for append");
        return false;
    }    
    
    char msg_buf[40];
    sprintf(msg_buf,"%s,%s,%.1f,%.1f,%.1f\n",params.a,params.b,params.c,params.d,params.e);
    
    // print msg_buf to verify is loaded correctly, e.g. [test,2024:01:01:00:00,30.5,62.1,60.0]
    printf("before write - msg_buf: %s\n", msg_buf);

    // tried using f_printf but no data written
    //f_printf(&fil, msg_buf); // <-- not writing to file
    
    // Tried using f_puts but i returnes -1 (no data written)
    //uint i = f_puts(msg_buf,&fil);

    uint i;
    printf("sizeof(msg_buf):%d\n",sizeof(msg_buf)); // <-- outputs 40
    f_write(&fil,msg_buf,sizeof(msg_buf),&i);
    printf("after write - characters written: %d\n", i); // <-- i returns 0
    
    // Close file
    if(!close_file()) return false;

    return true;
}

I've tried f_printf, f_puts and f_write functions.

fil not declared in function!.

Solved:  only needed to add FA_WRITE to the f_open() function:
fr = f_open(&fil, filename, FA_OPEN_APPEND | FA_WRITE);
